# #1060 - Duplicate column name 'Type' MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Anyone know how i can solve this? Sorry i'm still a newbie
also have this table done:

```
Structuregalaxy
Expand/Collapse
Columns Columns
NewNew
ColumnDiameter
ColumnDiscovery_Date
ColumnDistance_From_Earth
Columnid
Columnname
ColumnNumber_Of_Stars
ColumnThickness_Of_Stellar_Disk
ColumnType
ColumnVelocity_Extragalactic_Frames_Of_Conference
Expand/Collapse
Indexes Indexes
```

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE Black_Hole(
name VARCHAR(255),
    type VARCHAR(255),
    Location VARCHAR(255),
    size INT,
    Type VARCHAR(255),
    Velocity INT,
    galaxy_id  INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (galaxy_id)REFERENCES galaxy(id)

)
```

MySQL said: Documentation #1060 - Duplicate column name 'Type'

Comment: In MySQL, column names are never case sensitive.  So "`type`" and "`Type`" are seen as the same column name, hence the error message. Change one of the column names to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names must be unique within a table.

You've specified Type as a column twice.

Comment: Also, `type` is a reserved word, you should use \`type\`. [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden: a little more precise: `type` is a Keyword in MySQL but it's not a *reserved* word. (I think good practice avoids using keywords and reserved words as column names.)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Black_Hole( name VARCHAR(255), ***`type`*** VARCHAR(255), Location VARCHAR(255), size INT, ***`Type`*** VARCHAR(255), Velocity INT, galaxy_id INT, FOREIGN KEY (galaxy_id)REFERENCES galaxy(id)
)

> Duplicate column name **Type**.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring

```
type VARCHAR(255)
```

and

```
Type VARCHAR(255)
```

but MySQL is case insensitive, so it's basically the same column. Just remove the second declaration and it will works.